# Can't bind to DependencyProperty child of DependencyObject

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I can't figure out how to bind my image:

```
<Image Source="{ Binding  Path=ViewModel.MainViewModel.ProcessedImage }" Name="image1"/>
```

to DependencyProperty **ProcessedImage**, which is child element of my custom class derived from DependencyObject:

```
class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public static ViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

    [...]

    public BitmapImage ProcessedImage
    {
        get { return (BitmapImage)this.GetValue(ProcessedImageProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ProcessedImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProcessedImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ProcessedImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata());
}
```

I hope You can help me out with this. I've tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Why is your VM based off of DependencyObject? You should probably use INotifyPropertyChanged and set the DataContext in your view equal to your view model. Then you can just set the path to ProcessedImage, which can be a POCO

Comment: I've chosen this approach because it seemed simpler to me. I would rather keep it this way, if it is possible of course. Is it imposible to bind to children elements of DependencyObject class?

Comment: Just because something is simpler, does not mean it is necessarily right. The MVVM pattern is there to create easier maintenance later on. If you are going to create such dependencies to the UI, then you might as well stick with WinForms coding (you can use WPF to do that)

Comment: I've used this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) as a reference. It states: 
"In my opinion, a basic MVVM framework really only requires two things:

A class that is either a DependencyObject or implements INotifyPropertyChanged to fully support data-binding, and
Some sort of commanding support."

I know that your approach is more popular, still I want to try DependencyObject one. I'll keep searching for solution I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the data context? I copied your code and added another property - ProcessedImageName with a default value of "Hello World"

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProcessedImageNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ProcessedImageName", typeof(string), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata("Hello World"));

    public string ProcessedImageName {
get { return (string)this.GetValue(ProcessedImageNameProperty); }
set { this.SetValue(ProcessedImageNameProperty, value); }}
```

The I set the data context as follows:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel.MainViewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel.MainViewModel;
    }
```

The I set the binding path as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProcessedImageName }"/>
```

Personally, I wouldn't continue with the static MainViewModel property and would instead just new up a ViewModel instance as so

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

The path to a property is relative to the data context so if a property is Class.PropertyName and the data context is Class then the binding path is just PropertyName.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've nailed it!